# Debian Squeeze Server Can Ping IP Addresses but Not Domain Names

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, debian-squeeze

I just installed a server into a new open collocation facility yesterday.  I installed server software today, but during the install I could not connect to any of the Debian mirrors to get software updates.  I completed the bare minimum install from the CD.

After rebooting the system, I can ping IP addresses, but I cannot ping host names.

When I try:

```
ping google.com
ping: unknown host google.com
```

I have resorted to changing the host names in /etc/apt/sources.list to IP addresses, so I can at least update my server, but this is less than ideal.

Has anyone experienced this problem, or knows why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your DNS servers in /etc/resolv.conf or /etc/network/interfaces files. Try to ping them. Check your default route : is it OK ?

Comment: Check that DNS isn't being blocked by the firewall (both UDP and TCP are needed)

Comment: The DNS servers in /etc/resolve.conf and /etc/network/interfaces match exactly.  I cannot ping the servers, but the tech here says that the servers are not pingable.

Comment: I think there is a firewall between your host and the DNS servers. Ask your network administrator if there is one.

Comment: The network admin here got a Windows based laptop and is experiencing the same issue on his side, so it's definitely not a server configuration issue.  Thanks for replying.